# Decrease indentation of header text (fancyhdr) to 0.15 cm (same as \titleformat)

Tags: header-footer, indentation, fancyhdr

I'm using fancyhdr for the header.

I want to decrease the indentation of the text in it (header - italic text):

Now is like in the image

[image]

but I would like to have the same indentation in both (header and main matter- `\titleformat`= 0.15 cm). Any suggestion?

this is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin={25mm,25mm},hmargin={25mm,25mm},includefoot,headheight=15pt]{geometry}

\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,portuguese]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.65cm} % indentation
\usepackage{indent first}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

%sections format

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.15cm}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{0.65cm}\thesubsection.}{0.15cm}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\hspace{1.65cm}\thesubsubsection.}{0.15cm}{}

%mainmatter
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are much more likely to get a fast and useful answer if you can show us the code you use to produce the image and not only the output. Please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), so we can investigate your problem in more detail and don't have to resort to guessing. Can you also be more precise about what "indentation" you are talking about?

Comment: @moewe I hope that now is easier to help me! Thanks for you advice

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an MWE. A MWE is code one can copy and immediately run on one's PC. Please see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) on how to create a proper MWE. I am also still not sure what "indentation" you are on about. Can you make that more precise as well, please?

Comment: Now I think that the indentation is precise and the MWE is correct @moewe. Thanks again

Comment: Aha! I'm beginning to understand what it is you want changed...

Comment: The indentation looks the same. The indentation is to the base of the italic `I`. If you start a paragraph with italic, how does it look?

Comment: The difference is bigger between header and section, because the last one seems closer to the number. Mainly I want to know if it is possible to change the header indentation

Comment: @cfr if you open the .pdf of the MWE you will see a big difference also

Comment: Any idea? It would be very useful. Thanks in advance

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you want the I from introduction to start exactly `0.15cm` with respect to the left margin. The same value you used in `titleformat`. If so, can you add this information to the question?

Comment: Is it better this way? @Johannes_B